# Can a Telegram bot read his own messages on a channel

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to figure out why my bot is not aware of his own messages on a channel, when I use bot.get_updates() I receive only messages written by me and not by the bot.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [python-telegram-bot API description](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-telegram-bot/3.4#api), `getUpdates` fetches the messages sent to your bot, not the messages your bot sent. So it is intended behaviour that `getUpdates` would not be aware of the messages sent by your bot.

As a sidenote, as stated in the [Telegram Bots FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get), Telegram bots cannot access messages sent by other bots, regardless of the settings.